# optional parameter in object in function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a question about optional property used in function component in React.
There is a componentA, returns componentB which returns componentC. Originally,
there is only one property(property1) in ComponentAProperties and ComponentBProperties.
The goal is to add another property(property2) which is optional to ComponentAProperties
and ComponentBProperties so that if provided, ComponentC can comsume it. The code in
comment is what I propose for adding the property2. I would like to know if it is the
best approach?

```
interface ComponentAProperties {
    property1: string;
    //property2?: string;
}

export function ComponentA ({ property1 /*, property2 = ''*/ }: ComponentAProperties) {
    return 
        <ComponentB
            property1 = {property1}
            //property2 = {property2}
        />
}       


interface ComponentBProperties {
    property1: string;
    property2?: string;
}


export function ComponentB ({ property1 /*, property2 = ''*/ }: ComponentBProperties) {
    return
        <ComponentC
            property1 = {property1}
            // combineItems is a function that can accept any number of strings and
            // ignore empty string('') if provided.
            property2 = {combineItems(default, property2)}
        />
}
```

Comment: Seems reasonable. What are your concerns?

Comment: I am not very sure if it is the right way to pass optional property in the function argument.